# How to save ACE Code Editor data into a Rails model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, code-formatting

I want to save code into a simple model in Rails 4.1. Right now I'm saving the ACE data into a Rails form text area, which is put into a text field of my model. However, when I try to show the code in my index view, the code has line breaks and formatting removed. The documentation for jQuery-ace talks about access to the ACE instance, but I'm not really sure what that means or how to use it with a Rails model. This is the code in the documentation:

```
// Decorator
var decorator = $('.my-code-area').data('ace');

// ACE Code Editor instance
var aceInstance = decorator.ace;
```

I would guess that this returns a special Javascript object which includes "code" formatting such as line breaks. How can I use Rails to capture that information into my model, and then be able to regurgitate in a view someplace else?

Currently I'm instantiating the editor in a Rails form_for, like this:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, class: "my-code-area", rows: "8", style: "width: 100%" %>

<script>
  $('.my-code-area').ace({ theme: 'twilight', lang: 'ruby' })
</script>
```

Do I have to use the previously mentioned Javascript and also add some Javascript object to my Rails model, or something along those lines? Or do I also need to use ACE when I do my views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACE only formats your code text layout, so it should't make any changes to your model input.

You need to tell it to format the code on the `index` view as well, it supports `<div>`

something like:

```
<div class="my-code-area">
  <%= model.code_attribute %>
</div>

<script>
  $('.my-code-area').ace({ theme: 'twilight', lang: 'ruby' })
</script>
```

Comment: I found an issue with doing it this way. Especially when trying to submit the page. It seems to not save the contents.